# Embeding dependencies except type bundle

Tags: bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

In a POM parent I'm defining all common rules to build a bundle.
In the *Embed-Dependency* instruction I would like to write :

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;artifactId=!my-api;type=!bundle</Embed-Dependency>
```

"Embed all dependencies having scope compile or runtime except my-api artifact and bundle  typed dependencies."

It works for *scope* and *artifactId* constraints but **type!=bundle** doesn't seem to work.

All this to avoid having to specify the *provided* scope to bundle dependencies.

Any idea ?

Thks